# How to automatically log out user when browser closes?

Tags: php, javascript, logout

I have a chat program, which relies on whether the user is online or not to keep chatting. So I was wondering, is there a way to logout the user when he/she closes the WHOLE browser, not just the one window in like say, Safari, IE or Google Chrome?

Comment: You should ideally be using heartbeats to see if the user is online or not. What if the user is not closing the browser but their network connectivity is lost?

Comment: Is it fair-game to require [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websockets) or [some hackier "comet"-style long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))?

Comment: Ah, thanks a LOT for the edit sarnold!

Comment: View this thread, it should help you with your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839988/php-how-to-destroy-or-unset-session-when-user-close-the-browser-without-clicki

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9450736/575527

Comment: What do you mean by heartbeats, Ramesh?

Comment: I think the reliable solution is on a server side. For example client pings server some period of time (say every half a minute) and if there wasn't ping for a minute the server logs out the user.

Comment: I agree with Lion. Assuming your chat client will request new messages from the server. So once the client stops sending those requests for a certain period of time he/she is offline. alternatively.. read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303859/asp-net-and-sessions-new-browser-instance-versus-new-browser-window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing available via JavaScript which can be used to detect "WHOLE browser" exits.  If you need to be notified when a browser has completely exited (even defining this would be non-simplistic), consider developing browser extensions.

Comment: seriously? extensions? so instead of solving a JS/PHP problem (which can be solved in JS/PHP), you now suggest the OP to build extensions? how many browsers do you expect there are?

Comment: I've answered the question which was asked

Answer (score 1):

My browser is google chrome.  i have a idea:setttings-the last settings(more settings-the last)--to logout the user when he/she closes the  browser,like cookies and so on.